# What's is quickly method to deploy assets ? With setup:static-deploy?

Tags: command

In this blog I reference just options and argument https://blog.simon-axilais.fr/decouvrez-la-commande-magento-2-setupstatic-contentdeploy/.

And for quickly deploy what's is a best method ?
Thanks you for yours anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the Magento root directory in the terminal.
If you want to deploy the static content files, then please run this command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

The **`setup:static-content:deploy`** command is used to deploy static view files for Magento 2. These static files include CSS, JavaScript, and image files that are used by the front-end of a Magento 2 store.

Here's an example command to deploy the static assets for the English (**`en_US`**) locale:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

If you want to deploy the assets for multiple locales, you can specify them as a comma-separated list:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US fr_FR es_ES
```

You can also use the **`--theme`** option to deploy assets for a specific theme:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/luma en_US
```

This will deploy the assets for the Luma theme in the English (en_US) locale.

Finally, if you want to force the deployment of all static assets, you can use the **`--force`** option:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Let me know If any query.

**`THANKS.`**